The name 'T' isn't a type, so it can't be used as a type argument
How to use typedef with generics ?
How to use typedef inside a class ?
class Bar<T> {
  void bar() {
    print(T);
  }
}

class Foo<T> {
  Bar<T> merge(Bar<T> a, Bar<T> b, Bar<T> c) {
    a.bar();
    b.bar();
    return c;
  }
}

To avoid repeating Bar<T> I want to use typedef
typedef Baz = Bar<T>;

class Foo<T> {
  Baz merge(Baz a, Baz b, Baz c) {
    a.bar();
    b.bar();
    return c;
  }
}

But this is obviously wrong.

A typedef dependent on a type parameter inherently requires a type parameter.  It's not a macro where Baz would be textually replaced with Bar<T>.  What you want currently is not possible in Dart.  Maybe it someday could be possible if typedefs were allowed in non-global scopes.
